# How do I easily expose CRUD operations, via a Java based Web Service, on an existing data model?

Tags: java, web-services

I have an existing domain model annotated with JPA annotations that I would like to easily expose CRUD operations on via Web Services. I already have DAOs to perform CRUD operations on all of my entities in my domain.

Does anyone know of an way to do this that does not involve a tremendous amount of effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how my operations and services and what you call "a tremendous amount of effort."  You're likely to be disappointed if doing anything more than pushing a button and having your wishes come true is too much.

But there are three parts to your problem:

1. Writing DAOs that expose the CRUD operations.  I'd recommend an interface-based approach.
2. Exposing these as "contract-first" web services, either SOAP or REST.
3. Mapping HTTP requests and responses to your API.

I'd recommend Spring, because it'll help with DAOs, web services, and mapping.  But I don't know if it'll be as effortless as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html) in combination with [Spring ROO](http://www.springsource.org/roo/learn) to achieve this.

Please see this post for more details: http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=284028&postcount=4

Comment: Why would I prefer Apache CXF over Spring web services, especially if I was using Spring ROO?

Answer (score 0):

Throw some annotations on that DAO, like @WebService and @WebMethod and use your [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/) implementation of choice. You can use [JAX-WS Commons Spring](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/) for Spring integration.